# How to read dir in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3

In a VueJS application, I want to read the `public/images` folder and get all the filenames in that folder. How can I do this? I found some ideas. One is to use webpack like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var files = fs.readdirSync('/assets/images/');
```

But I wonder how I can use webpack in vue.

The other is to use Filereader. But I don't find an example with it. it is always with the `<input>` tag.
I have also read that node.js can be used.

Which would you recommend?

Comment: you want to do this as part of the bundling right? not as part of the deployed code - are you using some sort of frontend tooling? or are you using vue.js purely in a HTML file?

Comment: So far I am not using any frontend tooling. I have created the vue app with vite. I am having a component and a main.js and App.vie file. 
Is it common to use webpack with vuejs?

Comment: `not using any frontend tooling` OK, `I have created the vue app with vite` - go to vite homepage - *Vite ... Next Generation **Frontend Tooling*** did you not understand my question? `Is it common to use webpack with vuejs?` not if you're using vite, vite kind of does similar things to webpack, except it actually works

Comment: perhaps this is an xy problem ... WHY do you need to read that folder

Comment: In Vue.js, you cannot directly read directories or files from the client-side due to security restrictions imposed by web browsers. However, you can use server-side APIs to retrieve directory information and then pass it to your Vue.js application.

Comment: If I am using vite, is it possible to use it like in webpack:
`getIlmages () {
      const path = require('path')
      const fs = require('fs')
      fs.readdir(path.join(__dirname, 'assets/images'), (err, items) => {
        if (err) { console.log(err) }
        console.log(items)
      })
    }`

Comment: I think u want get html div ? Or i understood wrong?

Comment: I want to get the name of the image. So, I can use the name for working with it.